# How to make Oracle error messages more verbose?

Tags: oracle, ado.net, message

The message that drives me crazy is `ORA-01008 - Not all variables bound`.

Is there a way to know which one of the 42 possible variable names I have misspelled without staring at the monitor till my eyes pop out?

**Update:** I use `ADO.NET` to access the database. Perhaps it does lose some information in Oracle exceptions, as @Justin Cave has suggested. But I'm positive that the parameter name never appears even in SQL Plus.

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this too.  My default assumption is "this is enterprise software, you're screwed", but hopefully I'm wrong...  still, I'll never use Oracle again mostly for this reason.

Comment: +1, Good question. @meador, if you'd love to know the answer it indicates a good question. Vote it up!

Comment: DCookie: good call on the upvote... I thought I did that already.  my bad.

Comment: Can you post an example of the way you make the call? There are different ways and drivers.

Answer (score 2):

In general, Oracle provides the line and column number of any errors, but it is up to the particular API you are using (unless you happen to be writing an OCI application, which is probably unlikely) as to whether and how those APIs are called.  Since the answer is likely to end up being API-specific, what API are are you using and what does your code look like when the error occurs (i.e. JDBC, ODBC, OLE DB, etc)?

As an example, if I write a PL/SQL block with a misspelled variable name, SQL*Plus will report the line and column number of the error in addition to the error message.  Many APIs, on the other hand, will just report the PLS-00201 error by default.

```
SQL> declare
  2    i integer;
  3  begin
  4    j := 1;
  5  end;
  6  /
  j := 1;
  *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PLS-00201: identifier 'J' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Similarly, if you execute a SQL statement with an invalid variable name, SQL*Plus will get the column and line position and put a * under the offending character, i.e.

```
SQL> create table a( col1 number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into a( colN ) values ( 1 );
insert into a( colN ) values ( 1 )
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "COLN": invalid identifier
```

Most PL/SQL IDE's (TOAD, SQL Developer, etc.) will do something similar by interrogating the appropriate OCI APIs under the covers.  Precisely how this is done, however, will depend on the API.

Comment: Spot on. So, you can't make Oracle more verbose, but you can choose your tools so that the verbosity gets through to you. If your tools are fixed you're down to logging statements :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to get Oracle to make the error more specific.  Maybe some future version will improve this error message.

Instead of just staring at it, though, there are other things you can try.  For example, convert each variable in the SQL statement to a literal one at a time, until the error goes away.  If possible, generate the list of variable names instead of typing them manually.

Comment: Basically "divide and conquer".